# My Ethereum contract always revert the function that pull the data

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js

I've inserted some data into a Ethereum contract but when I try to call the function that pulls said data it calls a revert exception and cancel the transaction. I'm using Ethers to interact with the contract at Goerli testnet.

There is the contract code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Prontuario {
    struct Evolucao {
        string categoria;
        string titulo;
        string descricao;
        string data;
    }

    Evolucao [] public evolucoes; //Reestruturar para relacionar com o id dos pacientes/medicos

    function addEvolucao(string memory _categoria, string memory _titulo, string memory _descricao, string memory _data) public {
        Evolucao memory newEvolucao;
        newEvolucao.categoria = _categoria;
        newEvolucao.titulo = _titulo;
        newEvolucao.descricao = _descricao;
        newEvolucao.data = _data;

        evolucoes.push(newEvolucao);
    }

     function getAllEvolucoes() public view returns (Evolucao[] memory) {
         return evolucoes;
     }
}
```

I already tried to check the network but doesn't look like it's related to it because the write function works just fine, the contract syntax looks right as well

Here is the error I receive when I call the function:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code base and then I think this might be since you are using the dynamic array of struct. It causes the out of gas error and reverting when trying to scaling the array of struct. I suggest you use the mapping instead of dynamic array of struct. Please kinldy check the code below and I hope it might be helpful for you. Thanks.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Prontuario {
    struct Evolucao {
        string categoria;
        string titulo;
        string descricao;
        string data;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Evolucao) public evolucoes;
    uint256 private index;

    function addEvolucao(Evolucao memory _evolucao) public {
        evolucoes[index] = _evolucao;
        index += 1;
    }

    function getAllEvolucoes() public view returns (Evolucao[] memory) {
        Evolucao[] memory ret = new Evolucao[](index);
        for (uint i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            ret[i] = evolucoes[i];
        }
        return ret;
     }
}
```